# whats wrong in this code(Error: Invalid field ischecked for SObject Sample_Item__c )

Tags: apex, visualforce

I dont know whats wrong in this code im getting this error msg but im not getting the records

Error: Invalid field ischecked for SObject Sample_Item__c

class

```
public with sharing class sampleitem {

public PageReference doSelect() {
    List<sample_Item__c> lstswi = new List<sample_Item__c>();
    for(wrapperSample objws : lstWS){
        if(objws.ischecked == true){
            objws.swi.Item__c = pid;
            update objws.swi;
        }

    }
    return (new pagereference('/'+pid).setredirect(true));
}

public String pId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('pid');
public String wtId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('wid');
public List<sample_Item__c> lstSWI{get;set;}
public wrapperSample objWS{get;set;}
public List<wrapperSample> lstWS{get;set;}
public sampleitem(){
    lstSWI = new List<sample_Item__c>();
    lstSWI = new List<sample_Item__c>();
    lstSWI = [select id,name,Stage__r.Name,Item__r.name from sample_Item__c where Template__c =: wtId];
    lstWS = new List<wrapperSample>();
    for(sample_Item__c objSWI : lstSWI){
        objWS = new wrapperSample();
        objWS.swi = objSWI;
        lstWS.add(objWS);
    }
}

public class wrapperSample{
    public sample_Item__c swi{get;set;}
    public boolean ischecked{get;set;}
}
```

page

```
<apex:page controller="sampleitem">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageblock >
          <apex:pageblocksection >
              <apex:pageblocktable value="{!lstWS}" var="S">
                  <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                      <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!S.ischecked}"/>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                      <apex:outputtext value="{!S.swi.Name}"></apex:outputtext>
                  </apex:column>
                   <apex:column headerValue="Stage">
                      <apex:outputtext value="{!S.swi.Stage__r.Name}"></apex:outputtext>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Item Name">
                      <apex:outputtext value="{!S.swi.Item__r.name}"></apex:outputtext>
                  </apex:column>
              </apex:pageblocktable>
          </apex:pageblocksection>
          <apex:commandButton value="Select" Action="{!doSelect}"/>
      </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>

![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Looks fine to me - is the page definitely using that version of the controller (i.e. no compile errors).  Also, any chance this is an old error - i.e. what happens if you edit the page add a space and save it?

Comment: i Tried a lot but its not working

Comment: This line looks odd to me in the Constructor:  
objWS.swi = objSWI;  
Looks like you are setting a boolean = an object - shouldn't that be referencing a field on the Sample_Item__c object that is also a boolean?

Comment: I have seen weird problems when the class name is the same as an sObject Name. Can you change the class name from SampleItem to SampleItemClass or  something?

Comment: joshbirk - no it's not part of the custom object, it's a member on the wrapper class

Comment: Doesn't ischecked need to be set to a value? The declaration leaves it null and I don't see any assignments for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having switched in another test custom object of my own into your sample, this appears to compile and run fine for me? Stupid quesiton I know, but are you sure your controller is upto date with the server?

I guess the other difference between mine and yours is I removed the last two columns (since my test object didn't have those columns). However I don't see that making a difference. Anyway here is what I have and it works just fine...

```
public with sharing class sampleitem {

public PageReference doSelect() {
    List<test__c> lstswi = new List<test__c>();
    for(wrapperSample objws : lstWS){
        if(objws.ischecked == true){
            update objws.swi;
        }

    }
    return (new pagereference('/'+pid).setredirect(true));
}

public String pId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('pid');
public String wtId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('wid');
public List<test__c> lstSWI{get;set;}
public wrapperSample objWS{get;set;}
public List<wrapperSample> lstWS{get;set;}
public sampleitem(){
    lstSWI = new List<test__c>();
    lstSWI = new List<test__c>();
    lstSWI = [select id,name from test__c order by name];
    lstWS = new List<wrapperSample>();
    for(test__c objSWI : lstSWI){
        objWS = new wrapperSample();
        objWS.swi = objSWI;
        lstWS.add(objWS);
    }
}

public class wrapperSample{
    public test__c swi{get;set;}
    public boolean ischecked{get;set;}
}
}
```

And the VF page...

```
<apex:page controller="sampleitem">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageblock >
          <apex:pageblocksection >
              <apex:pageblocktable value="{!lstWS}" var="S">
                  <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                      <apex:inputcheckbox value="{!S.ischecked}"/>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                      <apex:outputtext value="{!S.swi.Name}"></apex:outputtext>
                  </apex:column>
              </apex:pageblocktable>
          </apex:pageblocksection>
          <apex:commandButton value="Select" Action="{!doSelect}"/>
      </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I get this...

[image]

Comment: but i Am not getting the output

Comment: Im nor getting the records

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the fact that your binding this APEX Class to the `<apex:dataTable>`.

I don't think you can bind APEX Classes to `dataTable` this way, *not positive*, but I think your limited to `sObject` fields, not members of classes in APEX.

Comment: `public List<wrapperSample> lstWS{get;set;}` so it works ok ;) You can bind `<apex:pageBlockTable>, dataTable, repeat` etc tags to any list or map. It's quite common for example to create small wrapper class consisting of Boolean isSelected + some real sObjects in it.

Comment: Ah I always encode wrappers for return in some other form like `@RemoteAction` so I didn't know if directly returning them to VF would cause an issue.