# Prepopulate custom field in Contact Object Based on its Related Account Object

Tags: custom-field, lookup, page-layout

We have a custom field named "Region__c" in the account object. The same field is also present in the Contact object.

When we select an account form the contact edit view we want to populate the contact's Region__c  field with the one present in the selected account record.
Simply we want to replicate what salesforce does with the address field: the contact MailingAddress field is automatically populated with the value of account's BillingAddress field when you select the account with the lookup search page.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily using workflow rule on Contact Object.

Comment: Can you expand this with a little more detail @sunny?

Comment: @sunny: thanks for response, but this won't resolve my problem! A workflow rule will execute when the record is saved. Only *after* the user has clicked the save button, the Contact.region__c field will be populated with the respective value from the related account object.
My need is to auto populate the Contact.region__c field in the edit view when the user select the related account  object. Example: if the account.region__c field contains 'France' then in the contact edit view region field will apper 'France'. The user is able to change this value or save the contact without change it.

Answer (score 1):

If this field should always contain the value of the account field, you can simply use a formula field.

```
account.region__c
```

Answer (score 0):

I've searched a lot, but the only solution I've found is to create a custom vf page and an apex class. Quite hard for such a simple thing.
This is a good point to start with.
[How to Populating Similar fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/how-to-populating-similar-fields)

Comment: Did you consider the other answers given ? If you had to use VF and Apex, the question probably didn't fully  cover the complexity of your scenario..